# Assigning a value inside a function and using it outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a reaction web application with firebase backend. Based on field query of one document, I wanted to access another document.

I'm only able to return the query and directly use it for accessing the document. It's making a call to the function and query over and over again.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { withAuthorization } from '../Session';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import './Image/1.jpeg'
import Album from './Album.js';

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        ...theme.mixins.gutters(),
        paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
        paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    },
});

class ChildPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            items: [],
        };
        this.classes = props;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true });

        let query = [];
        this.unsub = this.props.firebase.users().doc(this.props.firebase.userId()).get().then(doc => {
            query.push(doc.data().LinkedUsername)
            const lU = this.props.firebase.users().where("email", "==", query[0])
            lU.get().then(snapshot => {
                console.log(snapshot.docs[0].id)
            })
        })

        this.unsubscribe = this.props.firebase
            .users().doc(this.props.firebase.userId()).collection('tasks')
            .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                let items = [];
                snapshot.forEach(doc =>
                    (doc.data().status === false) ?
                        items.push({ ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id })
                        :
                        null
                );
                this.setState({
                    items,
                    loading: false,
                });
            });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unsubscribe();
        this.unsub();
    }

    removeItem(itemId) {
        const itemRef = this.props.firebase.users().doc(`${itemId}`);
        itemRef.remove();
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div className='background'>
                <div className='topBar'>
                </div>
                <Paper className={ this.classes.root } elevation={ 1 }>
                    <Album cards={ this.state.items } />
                </Paper>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const condition = authUser => !!authUser;

export default compose(
    withAuthorization(condition),
    withStyles(styles),
)(ChildPage)
```

I want the query to run one time and assign the return value to a variable. Then be able to use that value to access them and load the documents.

Currently, this gives me a document id in the console. And if I want to use that id, I take the next two "})" brackets and put them before
"
}

```
componentWillUnmount() {"
```

and take everything inside the console i.e. "snapshot.docs[0].id" and put it inplace of "this.props.firebase.userId()" in the doc of this.unsubscribe.

But it's what calls the function over and over and gives the error,

"Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version."

Comment: Hi Parvesh, it seems that the warning comes from your `<Album />` component. Can you console.log the cards prop that you send there? The issue says that you don't have valid element key prop inside the map function, as the key is an object instead of string or number.

Comment: Hi Vlatko. Thank you for your answer. Yes I'm able to console.log there. I'm also passing key in the Album.js